# Python package exclude folder

Tags: python

When running setup to package my app I exclude some directories using `find_packages(exclude`:

Here is my example setup.py

```
setup(
    name='test',
    packages=find_packages(exclude=['demo*']),
    include_package_data=True,
    version=app.__version__,
    description='test',
    url='https://github.com/?????',
    classifiers=[],
)
```

However then I unpack the package demo on PyPi and it still includes demo in the zip.

I have outputted the content of...

> find_packages(exclude=['demo*',]

which does not include demo folder as excepted, so I assumed it would be omitted. Why is demo being included? Have I forget something in my setup.py?